# My player character goes flying instead of movin slowly, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made this scrip to make my character move to the direction of my swipe, it does move but it is randomly and regardless of the direction of the swipe I make and it goes flying at full speed. How do I fix this?

That it'd go 0.5f move speed once to the direction of my swipe.

Heres my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Betu : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    bool left;
    bool right;
    public int pixel;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >1)
        {
            Touch finger = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (finger.deltaPosition.x > pixel)
            {
                right = true;
                left = false;   
            }

            if (finger.deltaPosition.x < -pixel)
            {
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }

        }


        if (right)
        {
            rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x + 0.5f, rb.position.y);
        }

        if (left)
        {
            rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x - 0.5f, rb.position.y);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that to constantly updating the player position left and right. What you should do is add boolean to fix that.

Below is the updated version of your code, please try it and let me know if you that fixes it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Betu : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool left;
    bool right;
    public int pixel;
    bool moveCharacter;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch finger = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (finger.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                if (finger.deltaPosition.x > pixel)
                {
                    right = true;
                    left = false;
                    moveCharacter = true;
                }

                if (finger.deltaPosition.x < -pixel)
                {
                    right = false;
                    left = true;
                    moveCharacter = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (moveCharacter)
        {
            if (right)
            {
                rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x + 0.5f, rb.position.y);
            }

            if (left)
            {
                rb.position = new Vector2(rb.position.x - 0.5f, rb.position.y);
            }
            moveCharacter = false;
        }
    }
}
```